# How to pass data with specific ID to backend route param?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I want to post a message to a backend route param with the current id.
How do I let the system know that I am passing this id?

Vuex action:

```
postMessage({commit}, payload, id) {
  axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/channels/${id}/messages` ,payload)
    .then((res) => {
      commit(SET_POSTS, res.data)
    })
}
```

This is posting the action but I need to pass the current channel id somehow. But the channel ID is in a different component?

```
postMessage() {
  const postData = {
    description: this.description,
    timestamp: this.timestamp
  };
  this.$store.dispatch("postMessage", postData)
},
```

In a different component I have a channel list in my side menu, like discord for example and I display it like this

```
 p.d-flex.align-items-center.channel-item(v-for="channel in channelName" :key="channel.id")
      strong.hash.mr-3 #
      | {{channel.channel_name}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the primary benefits of Vuex is the ability to set state in one component and get it from another.  In the other component, set some state like `state.id`.  Then you can either pass that id to the action, or get it from `state` inside the action.

Here's an example of passing it:

*Method*

```js
postMessage() {
  const postData = {
    id: this.$store.state.id,
    description: this.description,
    timestamp: this.timestamp
  };
  this.$store.dispatch("postMessage", postData)
}
```

Vuex actions always provide only 2 parameters, one for the context object (which contains `commit`, `dispatch`, etc.) and the payload.  Change your action to:

*Action*

```js
postMessage({ commit }, payload) {
  axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/channels/${payload.id}/messages`, payload)
    .then((res) => {
      commit(SET_POSTS, res.data)
    })
}
```

If you prefer, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the payload argument and use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to separate out the `id` from the rest:

*Action*

```js
postMessage({ commit }, { id, ...payload }) {
  axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/channels/${id}/messages`, payload)
    .then((res) => {
      commit(SET_POSTS, res.data)
    })
}
```

You could also leave the id out of the payload and take it directly from state in the action:

*Action*

```js
postMessage({ state, commit }, payload) {
  axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/channels/${state.id}/messages`, payload)
    .then((res) => {
      commit(SET_POSTS, res.data)
    })
}
```